# Share or access existing shell session

Tags: shell

Is there a way to access or create a shell in another user session?

I have a user doing their things on a DE (like KDE) and I'm connected as root on the computer through `ssh`. Is there a way to take control of an existing terminal on KDE or maybe create a shell as this user so all my actions execute on KDE, with all the needed environment variables and execution place needed (not in the `ssh` but on the KDE desktop)?

It's kind of a collaboration, because the other user is me too.

Comment: Not really, no. Unless you're talking about collaboration with the user

Comment: Actually yeah it's kind of collaboration, Because it's me on the KDE session and on a laptop it's me aswell through SSH

Comment: you could use [tag:screen] or [tag:tmux] to share a terminal session.

Comment: "_it's kind of collaboration_" - please add that to your question, because at the moment it sounds very much like you want to snoop (spy) on a different user.

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah but what if I want to take control after having lost control of KDE session (where there is no screen/tmux executed)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
sudo -u "$user" xargs -0a "/proc/$pid/environ" sh -c 'exec env -i -- "$@" bash' sh
```

To run `bash` as `$user` with the same environment as that of the `$pid` process. You'd pick one of `$user`'s processes that runs in their KDE session.

To hijack a terminal session, see the `reptyr` command.

Comment: `env: 'ePerProcess --enable-crashpad': No such file or directory
env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines`

Comment: Maybe a grep proc can be done to take a process from $user. And maybe a grep plasmashell can be done to take a process from the KDE session

Comment: bash is $wantedProgramExecuted? $pid is $wantedEnvPid?